# EntityFramework update fails randomly on SaveChanges / ASP.NET MVC / postbacks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm doing an entity update from a Postback in MVC:

```
ControlChartPeriod period = _controlChartPeriodService.Get(request.PeriodId);

if (period != null)
{
    SerializableStringDictionary dict = new SerializableStringDictionary();

    dict.Add("lambda", request.Lambda.ToString());
    dict.Add("h", request.h.ToString());
    dict.Add("k", request.k.ToString());

    period.Parameters = dict.ToXmlString();

    // ToDo : fails on save every now and then when one of the values changes; fails on Foreign Key being null
    try
    {
        _controlChartPeriodService.Update(period, request.PeriodId);
        return Ok(request);
    }
```

The update method looks like this:

```
public TObject Update(TObject updated, TKey key)
{
    if (updated == null)
        return null;

    TObject existing = _context.Set<TObject>().Find(key);
    if (existing != null)
    {
        _context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return existing;
}

public TObject Get(TKey id)
{
    return _context.Set<TObject>().Find(id);
}
```

The weird thing is first time I run it it usually works fine; if i do a second post back it does not work and fails on an EntityValidation error of a foreign key; however examining the entity the foreign key looks fine and is untouched.

Do I need to somehow synchronize the Context somewhere?

I've been trying to find the differences in when it succeeds or when it does not succeed.

I'm using Injection for the repositories:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped((_) => new DataContext(ConfigSettings.Database.ConnectionString));
    services.AddScoped<ControlChartPeriodService, ControlChartPeriodService>();
}
```

-- update:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ControlChartPoint> ControlChartPoints { get; set; }

[Required]
public virtual ControlChart ControlChart { get; set; }
public string Parameters { get; set; }
```

In the ControlChartMap we have the following:

```
HasMany(x => x.Periods)
    .WithRequired(c => c.ControlChart);
```

Comment: Not related to the issue, but I see you add `ControlChartPeriodService` to the `IServiceCollection` as implementation and interface. Should be `AddScoped<IControlChartPeriodService, ControlChartPeriodService>()`

Comment: Thanks, I have added all repositories this way as I have not created interfaces for them.

Comment: what does the "EntityValidation error of a foreign key" say?

Comment: It says that ControlChart which is a navigation property of period can't be null; however it is not null as it is dynamic loaded as an entity.

Comment: What does `ControlChartPeriod` look like? It's esp. important to see how the FK is configured.

Comment: I have updated original.

Comment: Sounds like it is an issue with the scope of the db context

Comment: Is your database mutli-user?  In a multi-user database the Find(key) key could return true and then another user could delete the key.  A good design would do operation like this in a database that is designed to lock operations that may have conflicts rather than implement in a c# client where conflicts can occur.

Comment: The database is multi-user as its an MVC app; but im just running it by myself currently. The one thing is that the page does not refresh in between as they are sent by jquery postbacks.

Comment: Are you sure that ControlChart property is loaded? That's a virtual property this means that if you have LazyLoad enabled it won't be loaded from database when calling Find() for ControlChartPeriod unless you add Include(). Problem with your POCO is that in my opinion you don't have ControlChartID property with attribute [ForeignKey(ControlChart)]. This way even if LazyLoading is enabled ControlChartID will be populated and you shouldn't see that exception anymore.

Comment: Did you change primary key in database (or add).  It appears that some items in the database have a null as the primary key.  What type database are you using?  I would use a tool to query database for for nulls in the primary key.  If you are using a SQL Server then use SSMS.

Comment: So if you try the EXACT same update twice (if that is even possible), the first one goes through and the second one fails - if so, this should have nothing to do with foreign keys since the master data is unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting that the loading of the *TObject* includes the relationship as well, seems to me your problem is in this line:

```
TObject existing = _context.Set<TObject>().Find(key);
```

*Find* will only load the *TObject* record but not its relationship(s) , and as there is no explicit reference in code to the *ControlChart* property it doesn't  get lazy loaded - which seems to be the behavior that you are expecting , so I'm assuming you have lazy-loading enabled

The fact that the relationship has been configured as

```
HasMany(x => x.Periods).WithRequired(c => c.ControlChart);
```

indicates that *TObject*'s  *ControlChart* property is meant to be a related set of *Periods*  but that doesn't mean that it will force the lazy-load of the relationship when loading a *TObject*.

(I personally try to avoid the reliance on lazy loading due to things like this, and prefer to actually disable it and to eagerly load the relationships via *Include*, or alternatively in a less measure, an explicit load , by using *Load*. It may be a matter of personal taste but I've found this way saves you from many headaches)

So If you have lazy loading enabled and like the way it works, make a reference to the *ControlChart* property at any point between the load and before saving, like

```
var chart= existing.ControlChart;
```

or something similar

Or for non-lazy-loading scenarios, although it can be used in any case:

```
 TObject existing = _context.Set<TObject>().Where(x=>x.Id==key).Include(x=> x.ControlChart).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have hacked in a simple load of the ControlChart object by now. This does actually solve the issue; but i'm still not sure how. I have looked at the objects and there seems no change in the DynamicProxy part of lazy load so there must be something that I do not see, good for now. I will update my data layer later to have more indepth queries for EF with less relying on LazyLoad

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the different object graphs you try to inject. The generic method could deal on a first pass but could fail on update. Simply also because the resulting SQL or Datastore engine language used does not result in the same upon Insert and Update ...

I exp. this and in my case it came from the Model behind. Look at the Foreign Ks constraints etc ... Some might have not be created properly hence the update failure after ...

Answer (score 0):

This is just a stab in the dark but...

In my experience, if Entity Framework is randomly working/not working, it's because I needed to use `async/await` to ensure data is successfully collected before the method gets to work.

This would perhaps explain why you're getting a null Foreign Key error. If the method gets ahead of itself, it's going to be attempting to work on a new TObject, rather than the one you want to collect from the database.

Try turning it into an async function and turn all the get/set methods into their Async versions.

i.e.

```
public async Task<TObject> Update(TObject updated, TKey key)
{
    if (updated == null)
        return null;

    TObject existing = await _context.Set<TObject>().FindAsync(key);
    if (existing != null)
    {
        _context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(updated);
        _ = await_context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    return existing;
}
```

Then in the main method (which should also be async)

```
try
{
    _ = await _controlChartPeriodService.Update(period, request.PeriodId);

    return Ok(request);
}
```